# Understanding YOLOv4-tiny training results

Tags: python, c, yolo

I am training Tiny YOLOv4 and get great results out of it, functionality wise. However, I am not able to understand the training logs that I get. I am given multiple losses (class loss (I have only one class), loss, IOU loss, avg loss, and total loss), each four times per epoch. I want to plot the relevant loss and the IOU per epoch but do not know which value to choose. In addition, I do not know what "v3" and "Region 30" and "Region 37" are referring to. I already checked the relevant papers, repos, tried googling and asking ChatGPT and would be grateful for your help. This is an excerpt of the logs:

```
loaded 32 images in 63.765 milliseconds
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 30 Avg (IOU: 0.500688), count: 12, class_loss = 133.547852, iou_loss = 0.091309, total_loss = 133.639160 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 37 Avg (IOU: 0.490458), count: 10, class_loss = 447.843597, iou_loss = 0.410095, total_loss = 448.253693 
total_bbox=22, rewritten_bbox=0.000000%
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 30 Avg (IOU: 0.549514), count: 5, class_loss = 133.405350, iou_loss = 0.028351, total_loss = 133.433701 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 37 Avg (IOU: 0.315040), count: 20, class_loss = 446.940216, iou_loss = 1.281342, total_loss = 448.221558 
total_bbox=47, rewritten_bbox=0.000000%
]2;1/1000: loss=290.4 time=unknown[1;37m1[0m: loss=[0;31m290.437[0m, avg loss=[0;31m290.437[0m, rate=0.000000, 483.468 milliseconds, 32 images, time remaining=unknown
```